# error al procesar el paquete linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic (--remove)

Tags: grub2, kernel

How can I elimate this linux package?

when I ran this command:
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic

return this error:

```
.......
Desinstalando linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic (5.19.0-32.33~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-32-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: splash: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic (--remove):
 el subproceso instalado paquete linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic script post-removal devolvió el código de salida de error 1
dpkg: demasiados errores, parando
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was correct like this:
run sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"

and reboot

the problem was that the quotation mark ["] was erroneus with this [“] but i dont know why or who did it?